# setFirstLineIsHeader (FlatFileItemReader) replacement in spring 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-3

I am using `FlatFileItemReader` to read CSV file through Spring Batch. But the requirement is that the column order is not constant and can change.

So how do I handle this? I believe `setFirstLineIsHeader` is missing from spring 3.0. So can't use that.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reproduce setFirstLineIsHeader behaviour: set `FlatFileItemReader.linesToSkip=1` to skip header and set `FlatFileItemReader.skippedLinesCallback` to manage skipped lined as header.